# ResponseEntity return type wildcard with swagger generated interface

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I want to know the difference between returning `ResponseEntity<?>` with wildcard **VS** `ResponseEntity<ABC.class>` as return type when Swagger generated API interface contains 2 different classes as return types, i.e one for an exception and another for normal flow.

My controller interface is :-

```java
   @Operation(summary = "Get user by user name", tags = { "user" })
   @ApiResponses(value = {
       @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))),
       @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid username supplied", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Error.class)))
   })
   @GetMapping(value = "/user/{username}", produces = { "application/xml", "application/json" })
   ResponseEntity<?> getUserByName(@PathVariable("username") String username);
```

the **@Schema** defines return type.

Can I use `ResponseEntity<User>` instead of the `<?>` for the `getUserByName` method ?

I have the the global exception handler `@ControllerAdvice` in my application which returns `ResponseEntity<Error>` .

Comment: Please edit the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for your question is simply `Yes`. Since you are using a Controller Adviser, you can directly define the endpoint return type as `User` in ResponseEntity**

Using a Wildcard(`ResponseEntity<?>`) as a return type, the symbol `?` defines that the return value of the controller method can be any type of ResponseEntity.

Using as `ResponseEntity<?>` or simply keep it as `ResponseEntity<>` are considered as raw type of its usage.

But really it is not a good practice to do so. So, you have to declare the exact return type of the controller method in this format `ResponseEntity<ABC>`.

Let's take this example java of method returning a list of objects(`List<Object>`).

It is possible on this list to add a `Car.class` type, a `Van.class` type. But how ever the consumer of a method should not have to deal with such disruptive questions and we have to define an exact type.

Yes you can use `ResponseEntity<User>` if your method returns a User type ResponseEntity.

I hope this'll help you to solve the issue :)